# R - lm, cooks.distance & Outliers by Group

Tags: r, lm

Code with the out-group working great:

```
  url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/ozone.csv"
    ozone <- read.csv(url)
    ozone <- head(ozone,20)
    mod <- lm(ozone_reading ~ ., data=ozone)
    cooksd <- cooks.distance(mod)
  influential <- as.numeric(names(cooksd)[(cooksd > 4*mean(cooksd, na.rm=T))])  # influential row numbers
(ozone[influential, ])  # influential observations.
```

As per my new requirements, I have to add a group and need to find outliers for each group. My code sample is like below. How I get cooks.distance and outliers by the group? please help

```
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/ozone.csv"
ozone <- read.csv(url)
ozone <- head(ozone,20)
ozone$season <- c('summer','summer','summer','summer','summer','summer','summer','summer','summer','summer',
                 'winter','winter','winter','winter','winter','winter','winter','winter','winter','winter')
```

Here I need to compute mod, cooksd and influential by group.

Comment: first please be careful of using `ozone[influential, ])` to subset data because the numbers in here refer to row names and not row numbers. What do you mean you need them by group, do you mean season? Have you tried to subset the data by each group and run a model to see the outliers?

Comment: Yes. I need by season. If I subset the data and run individually, then runs fine. But my use case has 100+ groups and I have to run all at once and find the outliers in each group. I hope I clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply generalize your process and call it with `by` (object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`) which subsets a data frame by one or more factors and passes subsets into a function to return a list of data frames equal to number of distinct groups:

```
proc_cooks_outlier <- function(df) { 
  mod <- lm(ozone_reading ~ ., data=transform(df, season=NULL))
  cooksd <- cooks.distance(mod)

  # influential row numbers
  influential <- as.integer(names(cooksd)[(cooksd > 4*mean(cooksd, na.rm=TRUE))])

  return(df[complete.cases(df[influential,]),])
}

outlier_df_list <- by(ozone, ozone$season, FUN=proc_cooks_outlier)

# REFERENCE INDIVIDUAL DFs
outlier_df_list$summer
outlier_df_list$winter
...

# COMBINE ALL INTO ONE DF
master_outlier_df <- do.call(rbind, unname(outlier_df_list))
```

Comment: Great solution. But I am getting this error...Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]): contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Comment: See update to remove the *season* field in `lm` call since it becomes a factor of one level in each subset.

Comment: Perfect. It is working as per requested. Appreciated for all your help.